# Proof that the Kolmogorov topology is indeed a topology over $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: general-topology

I want to proove that the Kolomogorov topology is a topology over $\mathbb{R}$, if you consider the Kolmogorov tolopogy:
$$τ_K=\{(a,\infty)\ |\  a\in\mathbb{R}\}\cup\{Ø, \mathbb{R}\}$$
I know I have to prove that:

1. $Ø$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are elements of $\tau_K$
2. The arbitrary union of elements of $τ_K$ is an element of $τ_K$
3. The finite intersection of elements of $τ_K$ is an element of $τ_K$

Comment: If you know what you have to prove then what is the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Well the first condition is part of the definition so that's no problem. Have you attempted to see what happens when you perform arbitrary unions and finite intersections?

Comment: Yes the problem is the unions and intersecstions. I don't know how to prove formally

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. For an infinite union, note that
$$
\bigcup_{a \in E}(a, \infty) = (\inf E, \infty) 
$$

Answer (score 2):

If $(a, \infty)$ and $(b, \infty)$ are two non-trivial open subsets of $\tau_K$ (we can restrict to those as intersection or unions with $\Bbb R$ or $\emptyset$ trivialise):

$$(a, +\infty) \cap (b, +\infty) = (\max(a,b), +\infty)$$ as ($x > a$ and $x > b$) iff $x > \max(a,b)$, which takes care of finite intersections.

If $(a_i, \infty), i \in I$ is any family of non-trivial open sets of $\tau_K$, then define $m:= \inf \{a_i\mid i \in I\}$ which always exists (but could be $-\infty$, otherwise it's some finite real) and then

$$\bigcup(a_i, +\infty) = (m, +\infty)$$

(If $x \in (a_i, +\infty)$ for some $i$, we have $x > a_i$ and also $m \le a_i$ as the infinitum is a lower bound), hence $x > m$ by transitivity and $x \in (m,+\infty)$. OTOH if $x \in (m +\infty)$ or $x > m$ then $x$ cannot be a lower bound for $\{a_i\mid i \in I\}$ as $m$ is its *largest* upperbound and $x>m$, so for some $i$, $x \not\le a_i$ so that $x > a_i$ for that $i$ and $x \in (a_i, +\infty)$ and thus in the left hand union.)

So $\tau_K$ is closed under finite intersections and all unions.